# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 do in background error with JSON

Tags: android, json, eclipse, android-asynctask, crash

I'm trying to **parse image to viewpager with asynctask into my app using JSON**.I've encounter this problem for 2days after I fixed my JSON problem,now I encounter another problem with Async task. **I've look through all the answers in stackoverflow**,unfortunately none of them solve my problem.So here's my code and error log,any help would be greatly appreciated.

json link-http://vina.harvestcamasu.com/vina/xml/image.json

```
package vinajson.img;



public class MainActivity extends Activity{
// url to make request
    private static String url ="http://vina.harvestcamasu.com/vina/xml/image.json";

    // JSON Node names
    static String TAG_GALLERY   = "Gallery";
    static String TAG_ARTIST    = "Artist";
    static String TAG_IMAGE     = "Image";
    static String TAG_ID        = "ID";
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        //hashmap for view
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imagelist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                try {
                    // Do something...
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                    json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                    // get Gallery JSONObject
                    JSONObject json_gallery=json.getJSONObject("Gallery");
                    // get Artist JSONObject
                    JSONObject json_artist=json_gallery.getJSONObject("Artist");
                    // get Image JSONArray

                    //getting array from image
                    JSONArray Image = null;
                    try {
                        Image = json_artist.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGE);
                        for (int i = 0; i < Image.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject m = Image.getJSONObject(i);

                            //adding hashlist into arraylist
                            imagelist.add(map);
                            images[i] = m.getString("PicURL");
                            System.out.println(m.getString("ID"));
                            System.out.println(m.getString("Name"));
                            System.out.println(m.getString("PicURL"));
                            System.out.println(m.getString("Date"));
                            System.out.println(m.getString("Caption"));


                        }
                        InputStream is1 = (InputStream) new URL(images[0]).getContent();
                        d1 = Drawable.createFromStream(is1, "src name");
...                         

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return json;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
                if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                //caption = result.getString(TAG_CAPTION);
                MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13);
                ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            }


        };
        task.execute((Void[]) null);

    }

}
```

And now for the error log.

```
    12-06 12:01:53.589: W/dalvikvm(29144): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4f1f8)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144): java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at vinajson.img.MyPagerAdapter.getCount(MyPagerAdapter.java:47)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:434)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at vinajson.img.MainActivity$1.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:200)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at vinajson.img.MainActivity$1.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:982)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
    12-06 12:01:53.597: E/AndroidRuntime(29144):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
    Method)
```

**Here's MyPagerAdapter.java**

```
package vinajson.img;




import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.content.Context;
....

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    //private String caption;
    private Drawable d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13;
    private JSONArray Image;

    public MyPagerAdapter( Drawable draw1, Drawable draw2,Drawable draw3,Drawable draw4,Drawable draw5,
            Drawable draw6,Drawable draw7,Drawable draw8,Drawable draw9,Drawable draw10,Drawable draw11,
            Drawable draw12,Drawable draw13){
        //caption = text;
        d1 = draw1;
        d2 = draw2;
        ....


    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Image.length();
    }
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        int resId = R.layout.first_page;
        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
             image1.setImageDrawable(d1);
            break;
        case 1:
             image1.setImageDrawable(d2);
            break;
        case 2:

             image1.setImageDrawable(d3);
            break;
        ....
        }

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }

    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
```

}

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but you should check out Volley, which is an awesome networking framework. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/

Comment: btw, look at your MainActivity.java:103, it's throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=12"

Comment: thanks,I fixed ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException problem,but now I encounter fatal exception:main problem.Error log updated.

Comment: The error is inside `MyPagerAdapter`, could you include its code in your post?

Comment: MyPagerAdapter.java:47 You probably didn't initialize before using it.

Comment: Here's the MyPagerAdapter.java,
how do I initialize it?line 47 is 
`public int getCount() {
        return Image.length();
    }`

Comment: I mean Image. You didn't assign anything to Image before calling Image.length()

Comment: Ahh okay I get what you mean let me try and fix that.

Comment: where is the mprogressdialog defined?

Comment: its defined as this `ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;` I just crop it out since it's not what causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed the problem by setting a fixed integer into my

```
public int getCount() {
    return 13;
}
```

now my apps runs though,but why cant I set it to  return Image.length();?
If anyone could enlighten me that would be greatly appreciated.

A big thanks to KevinT and Christopher Fransisco,with all the helpful hints and guide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Initialize your `JSONArray Image` on your constructor. When it calls

```
public int getCount() {
    return Image.length();
}
```

It's crashing into a null pointer exception.

**Note:** Also you should consider if `getCount()` should REALLY return the `JSONArray`

Comment: Should I use a fixed integer instead of returning the JSONArray?

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem by setting a fixed integer into my  `public int getCount() {
        return 13;
    }`

Comment: That could work but then you will have to change it every time your element quantity changes

Comment: @ Christopher Francisco ,Could you suggest any other method to do it?

Comment: well you could use a Drawable array instead of d1,d2,d3,d4.. and use the length property

Comment: Thank you for the advice,will try that and see how it goes.